# Why do I not have the r_member_social permission while I have been accepted for the Marketing Developer Platform?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working with the Linkedin API V2. I have asked permission for the Marketing developer platform because I need access to likes, viewst etc. of a share/post. My application was accepted and I received the product (Marketing developer platform) with a lot of new permissions like: rw_organization_admin, r_ads_reporting and more.
But I didn't receive the permission r_member_social, which I need for the tool I am building.

Here You can see the application that I entered to receive the Marketing developer platform: [Linkedin Application form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ehaV.png)

Does anyone know why I didn't receive this permission and what I can do to receive this permission?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for LinkedIn customer support, not a programming one.

Comment: @MartijnFl did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

That permission is closed now.

Offical References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lms-faq?view=li-lms-2022-12#how-do-i-get-access-to-r_member_social